# Users from GitHub OATH can't open jenkins job (error 404)

Tags: jenkins, github, oauth

We use Jenkins Blue Ocean with Github Authentication Plugin and GitHub Committer Authorization Strategy. Whole multibranch pipeline is working properly including triggering build from webhooks and enforcing jenkins status check for every pull request. Users which are not in our organization has no access to the Jenkins.

The problem is that non admin users are not able to open any job in classic jenkins. After clicking to a job name they will receive 404 instead of opening job page. The same happen when they click to Details link from pull request status check. However they are able to see all jenkins jobs from blue ocean.

Note that for jenkins admins both works all the time.

I've already tried to add non-admin user as a explicit collaborator but it had no effect (normally our developers are part of devel team which has access to the repository).

[image: Jenkins AUTH settings]

**EDIT**

FYI: I'm allowing following github scopes: `read:org,user:email` in Global GitHub OAuth Settings.

Following exception is throw when user tries to access pipeline page. I revoked access token and deleted user folder from `jenkins_home/users`. Exception is taken from STD jenkins output. It is also shown in in-app loggs in configuration page.

```html
Nov 12, 2018 3:49:22 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: has_recent_activity=1; path=/; expires=Mon, 12 Nov 2018 16:49:22 -0000". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Mon, 12 Nov 2018 16:49:22 -0000
Nov 12, 2018 3:49:22 PM com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform getSelectedProtocol
INFO: ALPN callback dropped: SPDY and HTTP/2 are disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?
Nov 12, 2018 3:49:39 PM hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler lambda$init$0
WARNING: null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:917)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapper.java:142)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionServletResponse.activate(CompressionServletResponse.java:61)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.activate(CompressionFilter.java:108)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.ResponseImpl.getCompressedOutputStream(ResponseImpl.java:302)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.createOutputStream(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:88)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.createXMLOutput(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:68)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:51)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:145)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.IndexViewDispatcher.dispatch(IndexViewDispatcher.java:30)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:801)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:243)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Not enough detail, need to show error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a very exact description of the problem we encountered. Discussion is https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54031
Adding the following to **JAVA_OPTS** seems to be a workaround for us:

```
-Dorg.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.compress=false
-Dhudson.model.AbstractItem.skipPermissionCheck=true
-Dhudson.model.Run.skipPermissionCheck=true
```

Comment: Adding just 2 last options fixed the problem
`Dhudson.model.AbstractItem.skipPermissionCheck=true`
`-Dhudson.model.Run.skipPermissionCheck=true`